# Google PageSpeed module: how to stop it to change the Cache-Control header on NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-pagespeed

I'm trying to stop Google's PageSpeed module to modify the `Cache-Control` header using nginx.

Within Apache I'm able to stop it with these two instructions:

```
ModPagespeedModifyCachingHeaders off
ModPagespeedDisableFilters extend_cache
```

Is there an equivalent of `ModPagespeedModifyCachingHeaders` on nginx?

I tried with:

```
pagespeed DisableFilters extend_cache;
```

and also

```
pagespeed RewriteLevel PassThrough;
```

In both cases it adds the header `Cache-Control: "max-age:300"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nginx you would need to add this to the config to force PageSpeed to leave the original caching headers:

```
pagespeed ModifyCachingHeaders off;
```

Find more here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration#ModifyCachingHeaders